# How to plot multiple graphs stacked above each other

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I need to plot a set of 9 or more data sets with a common x-axis. I was able to do it for 2 of them but the rest of them just don't appear. They have to be stacked one above the other. with a common x axis. I have attached the image of what I have been able to do so far.

[stack of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv1Dy.jpg)

I have used the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

file1 = '1.dat'
file2 = '10.dat'

data1 = pd.read_csv(file1, delimiter='\s+', header=None, engine='python')
data1.columns = ['M','B','C']

data2 = pd.read_csv(file2, delimiter='\s+', header=None, engine='python')
data2.columns = ['N','A','D']

def fit_data():
    fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(12,11))
    ax1= fig.add_subplot(211,)
    ax1.plot(data1['M'], data1['B'],   color='cornflowerblue', linestyle= '-', lw=0.5)
    ax1.scatter(data1['M'], data1['B'],  marker='o', color='red', s=25)
    ax1.errorbar(data1['M'], data1['B'], data1['C'], fmt='.', ecolor='red',color='red', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(211, sharex=ax1 )
    ax2.plot(data2['N'], data2['A'],   color='cornflowerblue', linestyle= '-', lw=0.5)
    ax2.scatter(data2['N'], data2['A'],  marker='o', color='blue', s=25)
    ax2.errorbar(data2['N'], data2['A'], data2['D'], fmt='.', ecolor='blue',color='blue', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False) # hide labels
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0) 


    ax1.tick_params(axis='both',which='minor',length=5,width=2,labelsize=18)
    ax1.tick_params(axis='both',which='major',length=8,width=2,labelsize=18)

    plt.savefig("1.pdf")
    #fig.set_size_inches(w=13,h=10)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


fit_data()
```

I read through stacking of plots but wasn't able to apply the same here.

I modified the code to this but this is what I get. [modified code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KWmz.jpg).
I need the stacking to be done to do a comparative study. Something like this image. [comparative study](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9dTR.jpg)

This is the part of the code I have modified and used.

```
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False) # hide labels
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0) # remove vertical space between subplots
```

Should it be done seperately for ax1, ax2 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

`plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)` removes the space between them.
You can have as many plots as you want:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

numer_of_plots = 9
X = np.random.random((numer_of_plots, 50))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=numer_of_plots, ncols=1)
for ax, x in zip(axs, X):
    ax.plot(range(50), x)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I have put in a little more details and the modifies code.